# Update one object in nested child in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to update the child element with id of the child element with _id in the following schema with mongoose .

The mongo document looks like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62d3fee5ae016e6fdb4b3689"),
    "participents" : [ 
        {
            "this_kills" : 0,
            "this_eliminated" : false,
            "this_score" : 0,
            "this_position" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("62d1c20e3fbeecbdeb945ad1"),
            "teamName" : "Dagger Gaming",
            "players" : [ 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913727000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1803fbeecbdeb945a93"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913736000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1883fbeecbdeb945a9f"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913737000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1893fbeecbdeb945aa1"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913738000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c18b3fbeecbdeb945aa3"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }
            ],
            "teamLogo" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dagger%20Gaming1657913870000.png",
            "teamLogo_name" : "Dagger Gaming1657913870000.png",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2022-07-15T19:37:50.895Z")
        }, 
        {
            "this_kills" : 0,
            "this_eliminated" : false,
            "this_score" : 0,
            "this_position" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("62d1c2123fbeecbdeb945ad3"),
            "teamName" : "Dagger Gaming",
            "players" : [ 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913729000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1823fbeecbdeb945a95"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913731000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1833fbeecbdeb945a97"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913732000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1853fbeecbdeb945a99"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913733000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1863fbeecbdeb945a9b"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : true
                }
            ],
            "teamLogo" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dagger%20Gaming1657913874000.png",
            "teamLogo_name" : "Dagger Gaming1657913874000.png",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2022-07-15T19:37:54.740Z")
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2022-07-17T12:21:57.886Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I am trying to update the following document with this query

```
Scoreboard.findByIdAndUpdate(
        boardId,
        {
          $set: {
            "participents.$[t].players.$[p].alive": false,
          },
        },
        { arrayFilters: [{ "t._id": teamId }, { "p.id": playerId }] }
      )
```

and the query should update the player object with alive :false , e.g.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62d3fee5ae016e6fdb4b3689"),
    "participents" : [ 
        {
            "this_kills" : 0,
            "this_eliminated" : false,
            "this_score" : 0,
            "this_position" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("62d1c20e3fbeecbdeb945ad1"),
            "teamName" : "Dagger Gaming",
            "players" : [ 
                {
                    "playerName" : "Biswas Sampad",
                    "playerCallSign" : "buntysama",
                    "playerImage" : "https://ruprod-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/Biswas%20Sampad1657913727000.png",
                    "id" : ObjectId("62d1c1803fbeecbdeb945a93"),
                    "kills" : 0,
                    "granades" : 0,
                    "playerScore" : 0,
                    "totalScore" : 0,
                    "matches" : 0,
                    "kdratio" : 0,
                    "alive" : false
                },
```

any help would be helpful.

Comment: Your query will work with a [regular update or updateOne](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5LfZKP8BOtO)

Comment: I tried but its showing err Error: Could not find path "participents.0._id" in schema